# .remove does not work out - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove an id, and .live is necessary, the code is below

```
$('.TS').live('click',function() {
    ("#"+$(this).attr('id')).remove();
});
```

The error got from chrome

Uncaught TypeError: Object #first has no method 'remove'

I tried removeId, but the above error message.

Appreciate all help

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Are you trying to remove the **id**, or the **element**? I'd tend to assume the element (lonesomeday's answer), but...

Comment: What is the ID of the element you want to remove?

Comment: You're missing an `$`. The middle line should read: `$("#"+$(this).attr('id')).remove();`. It would of course be better to do what lonesomeday suggested, but this is what's causing your bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `remove` method on a string.  You should make a jQuery selection using `this`:

```
$('.TS').live('click',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: That would remove any element with that class, I got number of spans with the same class, therefore the remove by id

Comment: @Jean `this` is the element on which the element was clicked, not the original selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although it is an indirect way but it works -

```
$('.TS').live('click',function() {
    $(this).attr('id','');
});
```